Movie where Michael Douglas kid is kidnapped
I remember watching a movie years ago, where there was an intense scene in which Michael Douglas son's kidnappers call his home asking for a ransom and he refuses to negotiate with them. He hears a gun shot and the call ends. His wife assumes that her son is dead and has a breakdown. Later on, Douglas goes on TV offering a large sum of money to whoever catches or has information about the kidnappers which aggravates the situation. 
I was certain that Michael Douglas was the main actor in this film but after looking up all Douglas' movies I can't seem to find any that matches this description. Maybe I'm confusing him with another actor. 
Any help would be appreciated. 

"Give me back my son!" lol

What you are looking for is definitely Ransom from 1996, which contains exactly the two plot elements you describe. But it was Mel Gibson and not Michael Douglas.

This could be Ransom, starring Mel Gibson:

Shaker calls Tom and demands to be paid. Tom replies that Sean must be returned or else the kidnappers will be hunted down. Tom hears Sean's voice screaming for his father. Shaker fires a shot heard over the phone before the call cuts off, leaving Tom and Kate believing their son is dead.


Watch the trailer


Upvote for being a minute earlier and more exhaustive.

I saw this film in the cinema when it came out - except it's Michael Douglas' daughter that get's kidnapped; not his son. It's called Don't Say A Word.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Given that the question already has an accepted answer (that the original asker accepted as the correct one) from a long time ago, it is likely not Don't Say A Word, apart from the fact that the plot details given by the asker don't match either.
